# Are Wii games multilanguage (EU Region)?

Tags: nintendo-wii

Are Wii games multilanguage in EU region?

I live in Italy but I found some very good prices on UK sites, so I am wondering if games sold there have Italian language included.

If there is no general rule and it depends on the publisher where can I find more information?

Comment: ...do you really care about the horrible dubs and translations usually seen in games? :) (I say this as an active member of the VALVe translation team for Italian.)

Comment: They are not for me, but for my nephew (6 years old). :D

Answer (score 3):

Games are locked by television regions. `NTSC-U/C` applies to USA & Canada, `NTSC-J` to Japan and [`PAL` applies to a set of countries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAL_region), which include the United Kingdom and Italy.

The language depends on the publisher/game; I have seen games have different amount of languages...

Comment: Thank you @Tom I know the region restrictions, but I am trying to understand if Wii games sold in EU contains multiple languages or not.

Comment: @Drake: That depends on the publisher/game; I have seen games have different amount of languages...

Answer (score 3):

From my experience working on localized games, usually Europe territory (which sometimes includes Australia too) is known as EFIGS, or English French Italian German Spanish.

So most *localized* games you might find in UK would be also in Italian. But they need to be localized, something that is usually stated on the box (which you might be able to look at even in Internet shops).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You could look in the [Nintendo Wii games database](http://wiitdb.com/) which language are included in the UK version. (The UK version should be the PAL one that include the English language.)